# Eclipse is invisible in system tray

Tags: eclipse, system-tray

I just installed Eclipse, but I got a problem, after I minimize the Eclipse than it's not visible on system tray. I also check the ALT+Tab but there also isn't visible. I had to kill the process and restart. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out:

I removed the eclipse:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove eclipse
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I installed again:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

And it's working now. I have no idea why didn't work before, case I have deleted the old ubuntu(10.04) and I installed the 12.04 from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

It spreads all the windows in current workspace.

You dont have to kill the application